# Automatic update custom DateTime object based on system time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I think my question is a bit confusing as I'm not really sure how should I give it a proper title.

Anyway, my question is because I'm getting current date on my server instead of system time (or device's time). How can I make it to act like a "clock"?

For example:

```
// I have a string of date retrieved from server, let's call it as "stringFromServer"
myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(stringFromServer);
```

So after the above line of codes, I need myDate to update every seconds so that I can use it anytime I want.

Let say the current time (get from *myDate*) is 09:00 and after 5 seconds I expect it to be updated to 09:05.

One of the solution I have in mind is in my *Update()* function,
I'll do something like this:

```
myDate.Value.AddSeconds(deltaTime);
```

But I'm looking for better solution and hopefully I can get some help here.

PS: The reason I'm not using system time is to prevent user changing the time in device's settings. So I have to update myDate whenever the user exit or reopen the app.

Comment: use a `Timer` and the `Tick` event?

Comment: Yea basically my Update() method is using Timer and Tick event. I was wondering is there any other solutions?

Comment: Dont use unity to calculate your time. Thats a bad idea. First of all you shouldnt even have to have unity running to have your time update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity3D, if you want an event to happen every X seconds, a good way to do that is to use an IEnumerator function.  So for example, if you want to keep track of a custom time variable you could have an IEnumerator like this:

```
IEnumerator UpdateServerTime()
{
    while(true)
    {
        myDate.Value.AddSeconds(1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

This example would continue to update your time varable by one second, every second.  As other users have mentioned in the comments, this is not the perfect way to keep track of time.  But it should achieve what you want, if you are looking to track time in unity.

It is important to remember that in order to use this method properly, you need to call it like so:

```
StartCoroutine(UpdateServerTime());
```